# StringBuilder Regex Needed For Creating Dymanic SQL Statement

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have the following SQL string defined as a StringBuilder and want to replace all the ? with their appropriate keys:

```
SELECT a.accountNumber, a.eventKey, a.createdAtUtc FROM myFirstTable a, mySecondTable b where a.eventKey = b.eventKey and a.status = ? and
a.accountNumber = ?
```

I was hoping to use the following `replace()` function to retrieve the corresponding values from a map that are stored without the prefix "a." or ".b" but having trouble getting it working:

```
private String replace(StringBuilder sqlBuilder, Map<String, String> filterMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : filterMap.entrySet()) {
        int startPositionOfKey = sqlBuilder.indexOf(entry.getKey());
        int startIndex = startPositionOfKey + entry.getKey().length() + 4;
        sqlBuilder.replace(startIndex, 1, "'" + entry.getValue() + "'");
    }
    return sqlBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Creating a query like this will leave you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look.

Comment: Please use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Not only should you be using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-), but those `?` characters exist specifically for use with PreparedStatement.

Comment: OK thanks, i tried with PreparedStatement and got it working as expected.